# Yelp API Produces Invalid Signature Error

Tags: python, yelp, oauth-1.0a

After looking at several articles online, StackOverflow, and the Yelp Google Group, I've been unable to figure out the problem to an `Invalid Signature` error being produced from my Yelp API request.

Here is the exact error:

```
{'error': {'text': 'Signature was invalid', 'description': 'Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: [some text here with keys]}}
```

And the code I've written to go along with it:

```
import rauth
import time

def get_results():

    #Obtain these from Yelp's manage access page
    consumer_key = ''
    consumer_secret = ''
    token = ''
    token_secret = ''

    session = rauth.OAuth1Session(
            consumer_key = consumer_key
            ,consumer_secret = consumer_secret
            ,access_token = token
            ,access_token_secret = token_secret)

    request = session.get("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=Boston&term=food")

    #Transforms the JSON API response into a Python dictionary
    data = request.json()
    print(data)
    session.close()

    return data

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(get_results())
```

So what exactly is causing this error? I've done some modifications prior to this attempt, and the previous attempts I made I got similar errors; except one time I only got a "**Invalid Signature**" error, with no "**Expect signature base string**" message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more steps to authentication as per the [docs](https://www.yelp.ie/developers/documentation/v2/authentication)

**Making a Request**

> Each request must contain the following OAuth protocol parameters:

```
OAuth Parameter Value
oauth_consumer_key  Your OAuth consumer key (from Manage API Access).
oauth_token The access token obtained (from Manage API Access).
oauth_signature_method  hmac-sha1
oauth_signature The generated request signature, signed with the oauth_token_secret obtained (from Manage API Access).
oauth_timestamp Timestamp for the request in seconds since the Unix epoch.
oauth_nonce A unique string randomly generated per request.
```

> These parameters may be passed in the HTTP (Authorization) header as URL query keys or in the POST data. Generating the OAuth signature is done by applying the HMAC-SHA1 with the oauth_token_secret. You may view your OAuth consumer key at Manage API Access. OAuth libraries are available to generate these requests.

You are not passing `oauth_timestamp` which is required or applying the HMAC-SHA1 so you get an `Invalid Signature` error, it is clearly outlined in the docs above what you need to send.

There is also an actual  [python yelp api](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/python) you could use but to make a request you can use  the example below based on the `request` function from the  [example code:](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/python/sample.py#L42) to make a request using `oauth2` and `requests`:

```
import requests
import oauth2

def request(url, url_params=None):
    consumer_key = ""
    consumer_secret = ""
    token = ""
    token_secret =""
    url_params = url_params or {}
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    oauth_request = oauth2.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=url_params)

    oauth_request.update(
        {
            'oauth_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
            'oauth_timestamp': oauth2.generate_timestamp(),
            'oauth_token': token,
            'oauth_consumer_key': consumer_key
        }
    )
    token = oauth2.Token(token, token_secret)
    oauth_request.sign_request(oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer, token)
    signed_url = oauth_request.to_url()

    print(u'Querying {0} ...'.format(url))

    return requests.get(signed_url).json()
```

Which using your url outputs a whole load of json, the start of which is:

```
Querying http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=Boston&term=food ...
{'region': {'center': {'longitude': -71.05460875, 'latitude': 42.35028894954365}, 'span': {'latitude_delta': 0.0325510910039668, 'longitude_delta': 0.04668455000000904}}, 'total': 8351, 'businesses': [{'name': "Giacomo's Ristorante", 'url': 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/giacomos-ristorante-boston', 'mobile_url': 'http://m.yelp.com/biz/giacomos-ristorante-boston', 'rating_img_url_large': 'http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/ccf2b76faa2c/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4.png', 'phone': 
...............................................................
...............................................................
```

I am not sure if the api supports python 3 but the code above was tested with python3 and python2 and it works fine, to install `oauth2` you can simple `pip install oauth2` and the same with requests if you don't have it installed.

Comment: Great answer, very detailed.

Comment: @FreddieV4, no prob, glad it helped.

Comment: I'm getting no response calling the method above? I ran the same url you used like this: `params = dict(location='Boston', term='food',)    request('http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?', url_params=params)`

Comment: Hi, yes I have. I literally just copied and pasted your code, filled in the 4 keys, then added logic to call the request function you created. Maybe it has to do with the version of python I'm running?

Comment: Oops! There was a typo with one of my keys & the url was wrong- but the latter didn't seem to matter. This worked: `params = dict(location='Boston', term='food',)                                                                                              rjson =request('http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?', url_params=params)          print rjson `

Answer (score 0):

Another common issue is that the servers time is out of sync. On linux, one can run

```
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```